# Websphere AS Servername WAS_SERVER_NAME in Logfile Name (Log4j)

Tags: log4j, websphere

In the server console of `WAS 7` there are variables like `WAS_SERVER_NAME`, but whenever I reference them via `${WAS_SERVER_NAME}` (either in the logfile name or as a line in the logfile) they return `null`. Although they contain a value. what am I missing?

Using `RollingFileAppender`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by dbreaux, WebSphere variables are not available as a System Property. The standard trick is to create a custom property for the JVM say WAS_SERVER_NAME which is assigned the value ${WAS_SERVER_NAME}.

WAS run time would assign the value to the JVM property and then it would be available to log4j.

HTH

Manglu

Answer (score 2):

Those are internal WebSphere variables. They have nothing to do with log4j.